# Why my reversing bits code written in Python gets this error?

Tags: python, bit

I get this problem in Leetcode:
https://leetcode.com/problems/reverse-bits/

So the input will be a decimal integer and I have to turn it into binary 32 bits.

And then I reverse it and turn it back to decimal.

For example:

Input:

```
8 (whose binary == 1000)
```

Output:

```
1 (whose binary == 0001)
```

Here is my code:

```
# n is input number
str1 = str('{0:0{1}b}'.format(n,32))
len_str = len(str1)
index_swap = len_str - 1
result = [0] * len_str

for i, char in enumerate(str1):
    result[index_swap-i] = char

return int(str(''.join(result)),2)
```

If I run this code in Leetcode online Judge, I will get this error:

```
TypeError: sequence item 0: expected string, int found
```

This error is raised by the input 0.

I have no idea why it will raise this error. My code seems to works well!

Comment: Your way of reversing a string is not pythontic. Don't program C in Python.

Comment: I was a C programmer before. You are right.. But in fact I don't know how to program pythontic...

Comment: I mean what is pythontic?

Comment: See https://docs.python.org/3.5/glossary.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
result = [0] * len_str
```

`len_str` is an int but a string was expected.
What should happen in that Line? Maybe:

```
result = [''  for x in xrange(len_str)]
```

which initialize an empty string of size `len_str`

Comment: For all future readers: Look at the Answer from Lutz Horn for a Pythonic solution. My Answer only aims at answering the question without giving code advice (which should be done at Code Review SE ;).

Answer (score 1):

```
# There ...
a = 8
b = "{0:b}".format(8)[::-1]
print(type(b), b)

# and back again.
c = int(b[::-1], base=2)
print(type(c), c)
```

Output

```
<class 'str'> 0001
<class 'int'> 8
```

See also [Reverse a string in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/931092/reverse-a-string-in-python)